# TypeError: Cannot cast IntervalArray to dtype float64 when transform(pd.qcut,x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here's my dataset

```
result  score
1       0.786
1       0.896
0       0.435
1       0.563
0       0.145
```

Here's my code

```
import pandas as pd
intervals = data.groupby('result')['score'].transform(pd.qcut, 10)
```

Here's the error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/interval.py in astype(self, dtype, copy)
    708         try:
--> 709             return np.asarray(self).astype(dtype, copy=copy)
    710         except (TypeError, ValueError) as err:

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-429b3ee3f973> in <module>
      1 data['score'] = pd.to_numeric(data['score'])
----> 2 intervals = data.groupby('result')['score'].transform(pd.qcut, 10)
      3 data['Bin_low'] = pd.IntervalIndex(intervals).left
      4 data['Bin_high'] = pd.IntervalIndex(intervals).right

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in transform(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    491 
    492         if not isinstance(func, str):
--> 493             return self._transform_general(
    494                 func, *args, engine=engine, engine_kwargs=engine_kwargs, **kwargs
    495             )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in _transform_general(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    557         dtype = self._selected_obj.dtype
    558         if is_numeric_dtype(dtype):
--> 559             result = maybe_downcast_to_dtype(result, dtype)
    560 
    561         result.name = self._selected_obj.name

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py in maybe_downcast_to_dtype(result, dtype)
    150         dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
    151 
--> 152     converted = maybe_downcast_numeric(result, dtype, do_round)
    153     if converted is not result:
    154         return converted

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py in maybe_downcast_numeric(result, dtype, do_round)
    250         and not is_string_dtype(result.dtype)
    251     ):
--> 252         return result.astype(dtype)
    253 
    254     return result

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
   5544         else:
   5545             # else, only a single dtype is given
-> 5546             new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors,)
   5547             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self, method="astype")
   5548 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    593         self, dtype, copy: bool = False, errors: str = "raise"
    594     ) -> "BlockManager":
--> 595         return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
    596 
    597     def convert(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in apply(self, f, align_keys, **kwargs)
    404                 applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    405             else:
--> 406                 applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    407             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    408 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    568         if self.is_extension:
    569             try:
--> 570                 values = self.values.astype(dtype)
    571             except (ValueError, TypeError):
    572                 if errors == "ignore":

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/interval.py in astype(self, dtype, copy)
    710         except (TypeError, ValueError) as err:
    711             msg = f"Cannot cast {type(self).__name__} to dtype {dtype}"
--> 712             raise TypeError(msg) from err
    713 
    714     @classmethod

TypeError: Cannot cast IntervalArray to dtype float64
```

What should I do to cast the IntervalArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `qcut` returns a Series with same indexing, you can just use `apply`, which works fine:

```
intervals = df.groupby('result')['score'].apply(pd.qcut, 10)
```

Output:

```
0                 (0.741, 0.786]
1                 (0.874, 0.896]
2                 (0.406, 0.435]
3    (0.5619999999999999, 0.608]
4                 (0.144, 0.174]
Name: score, dtype: interval
```

Comment: this actually produces the inverse for me. 4 is largest? Thoughts?